# How to make a kernel interface to user-level?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm building a syscall to kernel Linux, so I need to export a structure to use in user level. I've read some documentation and they said I need to use a `*.h` below `kernel/include/uapi` or use `make headers_install`. But nothing seems to work. gcc doesn't identify the data type I tried to export.

So, what are the prerequisites to use this command and what exactly it makes (what headers it export and under what conditions) ?

Comment: `whereas gcc doesn't identify the data type I tried to export.` - You should `#include` the header (`.h` file) which defines the data type. You should also add `-I` option to compiler, which adds directory with the header to the include directories list.

Comment: thank you so much. Have I any way to instruct compiler, or other thing, to include the header file in the standard directory automatically( to other installation)?

Comment: As far as I know (and tried several years ago), after `make headers_install` the headers under `uapi/` directory becomes in "standard" directory ... but only after you rebuild `libc` library against that directory, and rebuild `gcc` against new `libc` library. As you can see, making new kernel interface "standard" for the compiler is not so simple. So, it is much simpler to explicitly use `-I` option with kernel headers directory when needed.